# Sum of two positive denfinite matrices invertible -- where is my mistake?

Tags: inverse, positive-definite

I wrote the following statement:

> $A(t) = \sum_{i \le t} r(i) r(i)^\top + \alpha I_N$
>
> where $r(i) \in \mathbb{R}^N $.
>
> As a sum of positive definite matrices $r(i)r(i)^\top$ and a positive
>   definite matrix $\alpha I_N$, $A(t)$ is positive definite and
>   therefore invertible.

My teacher highlighted the following parts and told me that my statement was wrong:

> "As a sum of **positive definite** matrices $r(i)r(i)^\top$ and a
>   **positive definite** matrix $\alpha I_N$, $A(t)$ is positive definite and **therefore invertible.**"

What I found out from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544139/sum-of-positive-definite-matrices-still-positive-definite) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1820024/proving-that-xtx-lambda-a-is-invertible-when-lambda-0-a-is-a-large-m) are that
 $\alpha$ must be greater than zero which I did not mention and $r(i)r(i)^\top$ 
is positive semidefinite. However, due to his highlighting and writing a biiiig ***F*** next to the whole sentence, I feel like there is something else which is fundamentally wrong.

I'd appreciate any help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Example: if $N=2$ and $r(i)=(1,1)^T$, then $r(i)r(i)^T$ is not positive definite.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In your case, $r(i)r(i)^\top$ would be positive semidefinite. Does it affect the fact that A(i) is invertible?